# What's the difference between the .asciz and the .string assembler directives?

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, directive, gnu-assembler

I know that the `.ascii` directive doesn't put a null character at the end of the string, as the `.asciz` directive is used for that purpose. However, I don't know whether the `.string` directive puts a null character at the end of the string.

If it does append the null character, then what's the difference between the `.asciz` and the `.string` directives? To me, having both `.asciz` and `.string` seems redundant.

Comment: The synonyms may exist for compatibility with other (possibly ancient) assemblers.

Comment: The assembler manual links synonyms in at least one direction, but the official docs don't say that [`.string`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/String.html) has any synonyms, or that .ascii or .asciz have any synonyms.  e.g. `.zero`, `.space`, and `.skip` *are* synonyms.  Probably someone said "the name of this directive doesn't fit the semantics of how it's used in some cases, lets make an alias".  They can't just rename it without breaking backwards compat, like @Nate said.  Compat with vendor-supplied assemblers on some unix platforms is another likely reason.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [GNU Binutils docs on **as**](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/index.html#SEC_Contents):

[`.ascii "string"`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Ascii.html#Ascii) (Here for completeness)

> `.ascii` expects zero or more string literals [...] separated by commas. It assembles each string (with no automatic trailing zero byte) into consecutive addresses.

[`.asciz "string"`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Asciz.html#Asciz)

> `.asciz` is just like `.ascii`, but each string is followed by a zero byte. The "`z`" in '`.asciz`' stands for "zero".

[`.string "str", .string8 "str",  .string16 "str", .string32 "str",  .string64 "str"`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/String.html#String)

> Copy the characters in `str` to the object file. You may specify more than one string to copy, separated by commas. Unless otherwise specified for a particular machine, the assembler marks the end of each string with a 0 byte.
>
> [...]
>
> The variants `string16`, `string32` and `string64` differ from the `string` pseudo opcode in that each 8-bit character from `str` is copied and expanded to 16, 32 or 64 bits respectively. The expanded characters are stored in target endianness byte order.

To summarize, the differences between `.string` and `.asciz`:

- In certain architectures (listed below), `.string` will not add the null byte, when `.asciz` always will. To test your own system, you can do this:

  ```bash
    echo '.string ""' | gcc -c -o stdout.o -xassembler -; objdump -sj .text stdout.o
  ```

  If the first byte is `00`, then the null character was inserted.
- `.string` also has suffixes to expand characters to certain widths (16, 32, or 64), but by default it is 8.

As stated in the comments to the question, in simple use-cases, there is no difference other than semantics. They all support escape sequences and accept multiple arguments. Technically, however, the two pseudo-ops are handled differently by the preprocessor and are not aliases. (Contrast with `.zero` and `.skip`, which are aliases.)

---

Regarding `.string`, the docs mention two architectures that behave differently:

- HPPA (HP Precision Architecture) - does not add 0, but has a special `.stringz` directive for that.
- TI-C54X (A DSP chip from Texas Instruments) - zero-fills upper 8 bits of each word (2 bytes). Has a related `.pstring` directive that packs the characters and zero-fills unused space.

Digging through the source code in the `gas/config` folder, we can confirm this and find one more:

- IA64 (Intel Architecture) - `.string` and `.stringz` behave like HPPA.

Comment: The "how to determine" part is pretty easy if you have GAS built for that target.  Just try it and look at the object file.  Otherwise yeah, it's not documented, just buried in the source code I guess.

Comment: @PeterCordes @Calculuswhiz Where is located `gas/config`?, I would look up some gas directive implementation, but could not `locate gas/config` it? How can I find it?

Comment: @Herdsman It's in the source code folder. https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/binutils/